# Aligning the NavigationView's title with the ContentView in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, alignment

I'm having difficulties aligning the navigation title with
my content view in SwiftUI. This operation is trivial to do in UIKit especially using collection view flow layout.

**n.b.** This is for an experimental project and I'm using iOS 15.

I've tried many different approaches :

### 1. Using a list

- This gives us the right alignment between the navigation title, the header and cells on the iPhone 12 Max but not on the iPhone 12
- The scroll view doesn't extend over the edges as it would in the Apple Music app.

**Is there a way to fix the scroll view?**

#### iPhone 12 Max screenshot

[image]

#### iPhone 12 Screenshot

[image]

#### code

```swift
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      GeometryReader { proxy in
        let cellWidth = proxy.size.width * 0.4
        List {
          ForEach(0...10, id: \.self) { rowIndex in
            Section(header: Text("Unknown").font(.title2).redacted(reason: .placeholder)) {
              ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                LazyHStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 16) {
                  ForEach(0...10, id: \.self) { index in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 2) {
                      RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                        .frame(width: cellWidth, height: cellWidth)

                      VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 2) {
                        Text("Example")
                          .foregroundColor(.primary)
                          .font(.subheadline)
                          .lineLimit(1)
                          .redacted(reason: .placeholder)
                        
                        Text("Example")
                          .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                          .font(.subheadline)
                          .lineLimit(1)
                          .redacted(reason: .placeholder)
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        .listStyle(InsetListStyle())
        .navigationBarTitle("Experimental")
      }
    }
  }
```

### 2. Using a VStack and padding ...

- There doesn't seem to be a straightforward way to align the `VStack` and first cell with the title. For example on an iPhone 12 Pro Max, a padding of 20 gives the right alignment and on an iPhone 12 we will be off by 2 pixels or so using the same padding.
- Now the horizontal scrollviews behave as expected by padding only the first
  cell.

#### iPhone 12 Max Screenshot

[image]

#### iPhone 12 Screenshot

[image]

#### code

```swift
  var bodyUsingVStack: some View {
    NavigationView {
      GeometryReader { proxy in
        let cellWidth = proxy.size.width * 0.4
        ScrollView {
          VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 16) {
            ForEach(0...10, id: \.self) { rowIndex in
              Section(
                header: Text("Unknown")
                  .font(.title2)
                  .padding(.leading, 20)
//                  .redacted(reason: .placeholder)
              ) {
                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                  LazyHStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 16) {
                    ForEach(0...10, id: \.self) { index in
                      VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 2) {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                          .foregroundColor(.red)
                          .frame(width: cellWidth, height: cellWidth)
                        
                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 2) {
                          Text("Example")
                            .foregroundColor(.primary)
                            .font(.subheadline)
                            .lineLimit(1)
                            .redacted(reason: .placeholder)
                          
                          Text("Example")
                            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                            .font(.subheadline)
                            .lineLimit(1)
                            .redacted(reason: .placeholder)
                        }
                      }
                      .padding(.leading, index == 0 ? 22 : 0)
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        .listStyle(InsetListStyle())
        .navigationBarTitle("Experimental")
      }
    }
  }
```

3. Other ideas

- Using alignment guides doesn't seem to work
- Tempted to extend the underlying UINavigation view and capture the exact position of the title to calculate the correct padding.
- Test all iOS devices and predetermine the correct padding value for each device...

There must be a simpler way and it is crazy that SwiftUI allows so much flexibility and yet we often get stuck for hours or days trying to do trivial things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Measuring the padding on all iPhone models (and iPad) I realised that if the screen width is less than 414, padding is 16 and 24 otherwise.

```swift
import SwiftUI

public func margin(for width: Double) -> Double {
  guard !width.isZero else { return 0 }
  return width >= 414 ? 20 : 16
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest solution I found in which everything is aligned regardless of the device (not tested on iPad yet).

It uses [Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) to capture the frame of the large title view's label.

```swift
        .introspectNavigationController {
          let padding = $0.navigationBar
            .subviews.first { String(describing: type(of: $0)).hasSuffix("LargeTitleView") }?
            .subviews.first { $0 is UILabel }?
            .frame.origin.x ?? 0
          
          if !padding.isZero, self.padding != padding {
            self.padding = padding
          }
        }
```

#### Code

```swift
  @State private var padding: CGFloat = 0
  
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      GeometryReader { proxy in
        let cellWidth = proxy.size.width * 0.4
        ScrollView {
          VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 16) {
            ForEach(0...10, id: \.self) { rowIndex in
              Section(
                header: Text("Unknown")
                  .font(.title2)
                  .padding(.leading, padding)
                  .redacted(reason: .placeholder)
              ) {
                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                  LazyHStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 16) {
                    ForEach(0...10, id: \.self) { index in
                      VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 2) {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                          .foregroundColor(.red)
                          .frame(width: cellWidth, height: cellWidth)
                        
                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 2) {
                          Text("Example")
                            .foregroundColor(.primary)
                            .font(.subheadline)
                            .lineLimit(1)
                            .redacted(reason: .placeholder)
                          
                          Text("Example")
                            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                            .font(.subheadline)
                            .lineLimit(1)
                            .redacted(reason: .placeholder)
                        }
                      }
                      .padding(.leading, index == 0 ? padding : 0)
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        .listStyle(InsetListStyle())
        .navigationBarTitle("Experimental")
        .introspectNavigationController {
          let padding = $0.navigationBar
            .subviews.first { String(describing: type(of: $0)).hasSuffix("LargeTitleView") }?
            .subviews.first { $0 is UILabel }?
            .frame.origin.x ?? 0
          
          if !padding.isZero, self.padding != padding {
            self.padding = padding
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

#### Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I would do it by reading the padding, then using that to extend the width of the `ScrollView`.

Example below. Changes:

- `Cells` is a separate view because otherwise it couldn't compile in reasonable time (for me). Would change from machine-to-machine.
- Added `background` containing the `GeometryReader`.
- Added padding inside **and** outside of `ScrollView`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var padding: CGFloat?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            GeometryReader { proxy in
                let cellWidth = proxy.size.width * 0.4
                List {
                    ForEach(0...10, id: \.self) { rowIndex in
                        Section(header: Text("Unknown").font(.title2).redacted(reason: .placeholder)) {
                            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                                Cells(cellWidth: cellWidth)
                                    .background {
                                        if padding == nil {
                                            GeometryReader { geo in
                                                Color.clear.onAppear {
                                                    padding = geo.frame(in: .global).minX
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    .padding(.horizontal, padding ?? 0)
                            }
                            .padding(.horizontal, -(padding ?? 0))
                        }
                    }
                }
                .listStyle(InsetListStyle())
                .navigationBarTitle("Experimental")
            }
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
    }
}
```

```
struct Cells: View {
    let cellWidth: CGFloat

    var body: some View {
        LazyHStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 16) {
            ForEach(0...10, id: \.self) { index in
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 2) {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                        .frame(width: cellWidth, height: cellWidth)

                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 2) {
                        Text("Example")
                            .foregroundColor(.primary)
                            .font(.subheadline)
                            .lineLimit(1)
                            .redacted(reason: .placeholder)

                        Text("Example")
                            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                            .font(.subheadline)
                            .lineLimit(1)
                            .redacted(reason: .placeholder)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Maybe my question is a bit confusing... The goal is to have the large title view, the vertical stack and the first item of the horizontal stack align while allowing the horizontal scroll view take the full width. Apple's Music app does this. Take a look at the screenshot I posted in my own tentative answer. Cheers

Comment: @MycroftCanner Yeah, this answer just uses the default spacing of each of those elements. I fully understand what you are looking for now - I believe it's probably only possible with Introspect, because there is no other way (that I know of) to get a nav title's spacing.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help... I banged my head for two days on this

Comment: @Kugutsumen Unfortunately some things aren't very customisable in SwiftUI (yet) which is when I also have to drop into using Introspect. However, I'll leave this answer visible if anyone is looking to make a `ScrollView` full-width like this.